# Implement word boundaries with regex alternations and words that might not begin/end with a word character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-quote

I have the following code:

```
//Array filled with data from external file
$patterns = array('!test!', 'stuff1', 'all!!', '');

//Delete empty values in array
$patterns = array_filter($patterns);

foreach($patterns as &$item){
       $item = preg_quote($item);
}

$pattern = '/(\b|^|- |--|-)(?:'.implode('|', $patterns).')(-|--| -|\b|$)/i';

$clid = "I am the !test! stuff1 all!! string";

echo $clid;
$clid = trim(preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $clid));
echo $clid;
```

Output:

```
//I am the !test! stuff1 all!! string
//I am the !test! all!! string
```

I'm escaping the `!` with `preg_quote()`, so why?

I had a second problem, which is now solved, but I don't know why it happened.
Suppose `$clid = "I am Jörg Müller with special chars"`. If I remove the code line `$patterns = array_filter($patterns);` then the output after `preg_replace()` was `I am J`. I cannot find out why, but I solved the problem with `array_filter()`.

Comment: `!` is not a word character, so `\b` won't match in between `"  !"`

Comment: Got the problem! How can I solve this? Is there a "more general" `\b` which includes also `!` and this sort of characters

Comment: Perhaps a leading `(?<!\w)`, to check it's not preceded by a word character, and for the trailing: `(?!\w)`

Comment: Can you please explain better what you mean? Where should I insert those patterns?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using `\b` to assert for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). However, the character `"!"` is not a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and `\b` doesn't match in between `" !"`.

These are the word boundaries in `$clid`:

```
 I   a m   t h e   ! t e s t !   s t u f f 1   a l l ! !   s t r i n g
^ ^ ^   ^ ^     ^   ^       ^   ^           ^ ^     ^     ^           ^
```

You could use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that each item is:

1. `(?:-[- ]?| +)` matches `-[ ]`, `-`, `--` or one or more spaces.
2. `(?:-[- ]?|(?= )|$)` matches `-[ ]`, `-`, `--` or asserts it's followed by a space or the end of line.

**Regex**

```
$pattern = '/(?:-[- ]?| +)(?:'.implode('|', $patterns).')(?:-[- ]?|(?= )|$)/i';
```

**Code**

```
//Array filled with data from external file
$patterns = array('!test!', 'stuff1', 'all!!', '');

//Delete empty values in array
$patterns = array_filter($patterns);

foreach($patterns as &$item){
       $item = preg_quote($item);
}

$pattern = '/(?:-[- ]?| +)(?:'.implode('|', $patterns).')(?:-[- ]?|(?= )|$)/i';


$clid = "I am the !test! stuff1 all!! string and !test!! not matched";
$clid = trim(preg_replace($pattern, '', $clid));

echo $clid;
```

**Output**

```
I am the string and !test!! not matched
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/3hdEKr)</kbd>

---

---

As for your second question, you have an empty item in your array. So the regex would turn up to be:

```
(?:option1|option2|option3|)
                           ^
```

Notice there's a 4th option there: an **empty** subpattern. And an empty subpattern always matches. Your regex could be interpreted as:

```
/(\b|^|- |--|-)(-|--| -|\b|$)/i
```

which is why you had unexpected results

`array_filter()` solved your problem by removing empty items.

Comment: Thank you! But why the empty subpattern always acted with special characters?

Comment: So complete new pattern `(?<!\w)(- |--|-)?(?:' . implode('|', $patterns) . ')(-|--| -)?(?!\w)`. This way I will also match strings like `- TEST -` when having only `TEST` in $patterns, right?

Comment: with `TEST` inside `$patterns` I want to match `- TEST -, --TEST--, -TEST-, - TEST--, - TEST-, --TEST -, --TEST-, -TEST--, -TEST -, TEST`. The `?` after second and fourth groups says zero or one time, right? So, it should work as I wrote, am I wrong?

Comment: `- ?` means `-` OR `- ` (with and without space after?). Which is the exactly difference between starting a group with `?:` or without?

Comment: Yes `- ?` is a dash followed by an optional space. The difference is it doesn't use memory to capture the text matched by that group. You can read about non-capturing groups in http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Suppose `$patterns` contains `!stuff`, with this regex `!stuff!` will be evaluted, but it shouldn't. Ok for `-< >?` but I can't use this at the end, right? Because I am expecting `-` or `< >-`

Comment: I edited the answer to match the dashes, or to assert for spaces. If you find exceptions where it should/shouldn't match, please edit your question to clarify it further with some examples. However, I'm sure this would give you an idea of what you need to do to come up with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I will do that:

```
$clid = "I am the !test! stuff1 all!! string";

$items = ['!test!', 'stuff1', 'all!!', ''];

$pattern = array_reduce($items, function ($c, $i) {
    return empty($i) ? $c : $c . preg_quote($i, '~') . '|';
}, '~[- ]+(?:');

$pattern .= '(*F))(?=[- ])~u';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', ' ' . $clid . ' ');
$result = trim($result, "- \t\n\r\0\x0b");
```

[demo](https://eval.in/466636)

The idea is to check a space or an hyphen after the "word" with a lookahead. In this way this "separator" is not consumed and the pattern can deal with consecutive matches.

To avoid an alternation at the beginning of the pattern (like `(?:[- ]|^)[- ]*` that is slow), I add a space at the beginning of the source string that is removed after the replacement with `trim`.

The `(*F)` (that forces the pattern to fail) is only here because the alternation of items is build with `array_reduce` that lets a trailing `|` at the end.

The problem with characters out of the ASCII range is solved with the u modifier. With this modifier the regex engine is able to deal with UTF-8 encoded strings.